# Find value in collection

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, conditional-statements, javascript-objects

I'm trying to figure out the following challenge:

> Write a script in a programming language of your choice (I'm going with vanilla JS) that uses a loop and a conditional statement to find the value of the number of dogs in the following collection of key-value pairs. Depending on what language you’re using, it is acceptable to think of this variable as either a dictionary or an array of key-value pairs. Please only use logic that is native to the language without any external libraries:
>
> ```
> KennelCapacity = {cats: 7, hamsters: 12, birds: 21, dogs: 3, chickens: 1}
> ```

I'm trying to set up a for loop with an if/else statement, but I'm honestly not sure how to piece it together for a proper answer. How should I do this?

Comment: since it is key value pair as you mentioned given the key you can access the value `KennelCapacity['dogs']`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

So, this question is very strange, because in JavaScript you could just do `KennelCapacity.dogs` and get the number of the dogs.
But this is not the question, so the following would be a possible solution:

```js
const KennelCapacity = {
  cats: 7,
  hamsters: 12,
  birds: 21,
  dogs: 3,
  chickens: 1
};

let numberOfDogs;

// this gets [key, value] (here [animal, number]) of each key-value pair in the object
for (let [animal, number] of Object.entries(KennelCapacity)) {
  if (animal == "dogs") {
    numberOfDogs = number;
    break;
  }
}

console.log(numberOfDogs);
```

This code runs through your Object and gets each value-pair. (See [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) at MDN).
With the Javascript notation `[key, value]` you can split the given array in the key and value or in my example code `animal` and `value`.

In the if statement is checked if the key is `"dogs"`. If that is true, `numberOfDogs` is set to the number of dogs, that is stored as value in your object and the for loop is broken.

I hope, this helps you. If you have more questions, you are welcome to ask.

Comment: Hi thank you so much! I really appreciate the thorough explanation and I am now going over it myself.